# Isomorphic subgroups in $\mathcal{Z}_4 \times \mathcal{U}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Consider the group $ \mathcal Z_4\times\mathcal U_4$, where $\mathcal U_4$ is the group of units modulo $4$. Let $h=\{([2]_4,[3]_4)\}$ and $K=\{([2]_4,[1]_4)\}$. (Remember that the product operation is addition modulo $4$ in the first coordinate and multiplication modulo $4$ in the second.)
>
> - $\text{(a)}$ Show that $\mathcal H=(H,\otimes)$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal K=(K,\otimes)$ (where $\otimes$ is the product operation restricted to $H$ and $K$.)
> - $\text{(b)}$ Show that $(\mathcal Z_4\times\mathcal U_4)/\mathcal H$ is *not* isomorphic to $(\mathcal Z_4\times\mathcal U_4)/\mathcal K.\quad$(Hence, isomorphic subgroups do not guarantee isomorphic quotient groups.)

This is my answer, is it correct?

$\text{(a)}$ $H = \{([2]. [3]), ([0],[1])\}$

$K = \{([2], [1]), ([0],[1])\}$

Both $H$ and $K$ are groups of order $2$. Since all groups of order $2$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, they are isomorphic to each other. (If you need an explicit isomorphism, just map the identity $([0], [1])$ in $H$ to the same element in $K$, and then complete the map in the only way possible).

$\text{(b)}$ In $(\mathcal{Z}_4 \times \mathcal{U}_4) / H$, note that the $4$ elements are

$H$

$([1],[1])H = \{([3],[3]), ([1],[1])\}$

$([0],[3])H = \{([2],[1]), ([0],[3])\}$

$([3],[1])H = \{([1],[3]), ([3],[1])\}$

Note that

$(([1],[1])H)^2 = \{([2],[1]), ([0],[3])\} = ([0],[3])H$

$(([1],[1])H)^3 = \{([3],[1]), ([1],[3])\} = ([3],[1])H$

$(([1],[1])H)^4 = \{([0],[1]), ([2],[3])\} = H$

So $(\mathcal{Z}_4 \times \mathcal{U}_4) / H$ has an element of order $4$ and is thus cyclic.

Now the 4 elements of $(\mathcal{Z}_4 \times \mathcal{U}_4) / K$ are

$K = \{([2], [1]), ([0],[1])\}$

$([1],[1]) K = \{([3], [1]), ([1],[1])\}$

$([0],[3]) K = \{([2], [3]), ([0],[3])\}$

$([1],[3]) K = \{([3], [3]), ([1],[3])\}$

Note that

$(([1],[1]) K)^2 = \{([0], [1]), ([2],[1])\} = K$

$(([0],[3]) K)^2 = \{([2], [1]), ([0],[1])\} = K$

$(([1],[3]) K^2 = \{([0], [1]), ([2],[1])\} = K$

So all nonidentity elements in $(\mathcal{Z}_4 \times \mathcal{U}_4) / K$ have order $2$, so $(\mathcal{Z}_4 \times \mathcal{U}_4) / K$ is not cyclic, and is thus not isomorphic to
$(\mathcal{Z}_4 \times \mathcal{U}_4) / H$.

Answer (score 0):

Seems correct to me!

A way to do part $b$ slightly more cleanly: show that any element of $(\mathcal{Z}_4 \times \mathcal{U}_4)$ squared is in $K$, that way you don't have to check every element.